# ERROR While Creating Archive : bitcode bundle could not be generated because 'Library Path(filename.o)' was built without full bit code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, watchos-2

I have created library for my Apple watch based on the  [`Ray Wenderlich Tutorial`](https://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial). Steps I fallowed in brief.

Step 1 : I chosen template as Xcode -> File -> New -> watchOS -> Framework & Library -> Watch Static Library

Step 2 : Added files which are needed to make as library.

step 3 : Added header files in the library build in to public files.

step 4 : Run the application

step 5 : I want to create a universal library so I added target as Xcode -> File -> New -> Target -> Other -> Aggregate

step 6 : Added run script for simulator and watch os as

```
# define output folder environment variable
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

xcodebuild -target RBWatchModelManager ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 -arch i386  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

UNIVERSAL_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_BUILD_DIR}"

# Step 2. Create universal binary file using lipo

lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-watchos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"

# Last touch. copy the header files. Just for convenience
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/include" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
```

and I tried one more script but tried either one of these two available scripts

```
# define output folder environment variable
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target RBIWatchModelManager ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
xcodebuild -target RBIWatchModelManager -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

xcodebuild -target RBIWatchModelManager ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk watchos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 2. Create universal binary file using lipo
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-watchos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"

# Last touch. copy the header files. Just for convenience
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/include" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
```

Using any one of this script i Created Library successfully.

Step 7 : I added this library (Universal folder library and header files (include folder)) to my actual project.

step 8 : selected library in the build phases `Link Binary with Libraries`

step 9 : Added Header search Path

Step 10 : Run the application. In simulator, and Device its running properly.

But While creating Archive of this project, I'm getting one error as shown in the image below.

Then I searched about this error, I tried the suggestion :

Suggestion I tried :

1. Changing the bit code. Because of I'm using watchOS there is no bit code option available in build settings while creating library So there is no scope for this solution.
2. Added `-fembed-bitcode` for `Custom Compiler Flags` in build setting of the Library while creating it. But no use. I'm getting the same error.
3. I thought this error because of particular file name showed in the error log. So I tried of separating those files and I created new library but then I'm getting same error for other files that are used for creating library. So no use..
4. I tried of enabling and disabling `Enable Bitcode` Option in Build settings of my original project where i have added this created library, no use at all.

At finally... Is there any other solution available to resolve this error. And One thing from apple i found is

> For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. For watchOS and
>   tvOS apps, bitcode is required. If you provide bitcode, all apps and
>   frameworks in the app bundle (all targets in the project) need to
>   include bitcode.
>       After you distribute your app using iTunes Connect, you can download the dSYMs file for the build, described in Viewing and
>   Importing Crashes in the Devices Window.

Help me out ??

[image: Error while creating archive]

Comment: Since the tutorial you are following (is 3 years old, and) was written well before watchOS or bitcode was even announced, perhaps step 0 should be to use a more recent tutorial that addresses watchOS and bitcode issues?

Comment: Well If you go through all the steps that I have used, you might know the reason where exactly i'm doing the mistake ? It doesn't always wrong if we use the old approach until we have a proper reason. And about bit code, apple says bit code is enable for apple watch build by default and there is no option to change it. And yes I didn't get Step 0, tutorial